# Excel - Count multiple occurances of a value based on a critera

Tags: excel, criteria, countif

I am trying to count occurances of an account number appearing in column A only when the value in column B = "abc".

`COUNTIFS(data!G2:N173529,A2)` returns the count where the account number appears. However, it returns the complete count without filtering based on column B. How can I add another criteria to further simplify the count based on column B.

UPDATE:
`(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$173529,A2)>1,"Multiple Matches",VLOOKUP(A2,C:M,7,FALSE))`
This returns value from column 7 where A2 value appears once in column C and returns "Multiple Matches" where A2 appears more than once in column C.

However, how do I add the second criteria to check if text "abc" appears in column B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use countifs

`=COUNTIFS(data!G:N,A2,B:B,"abc")`

example:

```
check   check   "abc"   
        heck    "abc"   
        speck   "abc"   
        check   " abc"  
        check   "abc"   
        check   "1abc"
```

I put `=countifs(B:B,A1,C:C,"abc")`

which correctly returned 2

Comment: not working. I tried the following:
`IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$173529,A2)>1,"Multiple Matches",VLOOKUP(A2,C:M,7,FALSE))` but this returns value from column 7 where A2 value appears once in column C and returns "Multiple Matches" where A2 appears more than once in column C. However, still not able to fit the other criteria of filtering the count based on value in column B

Comment: did you try `=COUNTIFS(data!G:N,A2,B:B,"abc")` with two criteria? That was my suggestion

Comment: Yes I did, it returned me 0 although there are multiple occurances
=COUNTIFS(C:C,A2,J:J,"abc")

Comment: The formula will work only if there are cells in the J column with values of exactly "abc". For instance "1 abc" "1, abc" " abc" "abc " will not work (see my revised example above)